# Single Charge with Stripe in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm trying to figure out how to accept credit card using stripe in a single charge that is entered within the forms input field.

Example: user1 logged in and creates a post, entered $20 in a field and clicks submit. The post gets created and $20 gets charged to his card. User2 does the same but puts $45 and enters his credit card and submits the form.

I've got the following done;
- devise setup
- roles
- stripe gem installed and account setup

I haven't found an example that would explain a single charge to stripe, everything is subscription based.

I'm new to this, so I'm trying to mimic the subscription examples but without success.

Comment: I'm using Stripe with the ActiveMerchant gem - https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant and using it to place a single charge.  I can post an answer of what I did if you think it will help.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-stripe-membership-saas ?

Comment: Yes but that's subscription based. I need to allow the registered user to enter his own amount into an input text field and then collect his credit card data and send it all to stripe while creating the entry within the db.

Comment: Another way that this could work is if somehow I can assign the text input value to something like :price and be able to use it within a view and controller. That would work too, any idea how to do that maybe?

Comment: Would this work? In the view I would have <%= f.text_field, :price %> and in the controller for the stripe charge create have amount => params[:price].... shouldn't that work? So when submitted it runs the creation and the charge.

Comment: anyone? seems that I can pass a hash to controller but I can't find anywhere a good instruction on setting Stripe in models, controllers, etc.. to send data within the controllers def create

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I am executing a single charge using Stripe and the ActiveMerchant gem.

```
transaction = ActiveMerchant::Billing::StripeGateway.new(:login => STRIPE_SECRET_KEY)

paymentInfo = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
            :number             => "4242424242424242",
            :month              => "12",
            :year               => "2020",
            :verification_value => "411")

purchaseOptions = {:billing_address => {
    :name     => "Customer Name",
    :address1 => "Customer Address Line 1",
    :city     => "Customer City",
    :state    => "Customer State",
    :zip      => "Customer Zip Code"
}}

response = transaction.purchase((17.50 * 100).to_i, paymentInfo, purchaseOptions)

if response.success? then
  logger.debug "charge successful"
end
```

Comment: Hi @Jeff Steil, Thank you for this answer, I did the same and i got this error: params:
 error:
 type: invalid_request_error
 message: Sending credit card numbers directly to the Stripe API is generally unsafe.
 We suggest you use test tokens that map to the test card you are using, see
 https://stripe.com/docs/testing.
if you have any idea about it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Stripe.js in order to get a token, then pass that token string instead of credit card object.

For testing purposes, you can go to https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js and obtain a token from the form like in this image:
[image]

How to use it in rails console:

```
gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::StripeGateway.new(:login => STRIPE_SECRET_KEY)
gateway.purchase(1200, "tok_1E0CzPDdSOg3FLH0IFmWo1T2")
```